# parametrize @Interface annotation in Java

Tags: java, junit5

I have an @interface annotation type like this -

```
public @interface someAnnotation {
    String someVar() default "var_value";
}
```

I want to parametrize `someVar` on a Junit5 test similar to this

```
@ParametrizedTest
@ValueSource(strings = {"val1","val2"})
@someAnnotation(someVar = ??)
void theTestMethod(String s){
    //test something
}
```

I want the value of s (that is provided by valueSource) to be loaded to someVar. Obviously something like this won't work -

```
@someAnnotation(someVar = s)
```

I have also tried using Test Extension by implementing `BeforeEachCallback` to get `ExtensionContext` using which someVar can be accessed but I have found no way to get ValueSource values or method parameters values from `ExtensionContext`. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  Why does the string need to be stored in an annotation?  This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 5):

The Java Language Specification [section on annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.1) says, in brief, that element values must not be `null` and may only be:

- constant expressions
- class literals
- enum constants
- arrays whose elements are one of the above

Therefore, what you're asking for isn't permitted by the language.

The only way I know of to achieve this kind of variability over an annotation's values in a test would be to have the test generate source code and compile it on the fly (or, equivalently, generate bytecode directly).

Stylistically, I would argue that unless your `@ValueSource` has more than ~50 elements, it's simpler and clearer to the reader to just write out each case like:

```
@Test
@someAnnotation(someVar = "val1")
void theTestMethodVal1(){
    theTestMethodHelper("val1");
}

@Test
@someAnnotation(someVar = "val2")
void theTestMethodVal2(){
    theTestMethodHelper("val2");
}

void theTestMethodHelper(String s){
    //test something
}
```

All that having been said, it's not clear to me what the goal of tests like this might be.

As is clear from the hard-coding of `"val1"` and `"val2"` in the bodies of the above methods, it's much clearer and more concise to simply inline a needed value in the body of a method, rather than jumping through the reflection hoops that would be necessary to read that same value dynamically from an annotation on the method.